# Unable to go to previous activity from current activity on back button pressed

Tags: android, android-activity

//  It takes more than 3 press on the back button to go to previous activity.

//   This is my main activity

public class Splash extends Activity implements  View.OnTouchListener {
    ImageButton Ih,Re;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e("Harsha  ", "Create");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
   Ih= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.IH);
    Re= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Reg);
    anim3=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rightleft);
    Ih.setOnTouchListener(this);
    Re.setOnTouchListener(this);


}






@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.IH :
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,Second.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.Reg:
            Intent intent2=new Intent(this,Register.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: In all devices? And have you overridden onBackPressed? If so, show code.

Comment: that probably means you are executing too much calculation on the UI thread.

Comment: Show the code and we may be able to help

Comment: that's my current class

Comment: And it happens in all devices.

Comment: Show code how you open the Second activity from the first one , you only shown us the code for Second activity class only

Comment: I have the same problem. The same code takes 4 clicks on 4.4.2 and 2 clicks on 4.2.2 (two different devices) to return to previous activity.

Answer (score 0):

use this code into your activity to go previous activity 
 by just one click on back button of device
just copy paste it

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // code here to show dialog
     super.onBackPressed();  
     finish();
}
```

or you can use this also

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: use edited answers second option hope it will help you

Comment: I have a frameLayout in my main activity which contains 4 linear layouts and three are made invisible intentionally, can that be a problem?

Comment: no there is no connection of linear layout with your back button this methods are inherited method so there is no connction between them

Comment: Any other reasons which may cause this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may be call `finish()` on the time of call new `Intent`. If you call `finish()` then Activity `destroyed`. If it so remove finish()

And In Your second activity implement `onKeyDown()` function.

```
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Log.e("back key pressed","Back key pressed");
     finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on two different devices with different API versions..

So I just moved my code in OnClick vs onTouch...

The OnTouch event is more involved - it gets triggered onDown, onUp, onMove .. so for buttons is proper to be onClick

```
   this.findViewById(R.id.btnOptions).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It was at the beginning when I started android and Java. I was performing too many operations on UI thread and hence I had that problem which I realized later and fixed it..

Comment: how did u fix it? 
you should post your own solution :)